# react vite starting erorr pls fix this?

Tags: reactjs

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/index.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js:2:14:
  2 │ export * from "./modifiers/index.js"; // eslint-disable-next-line im...
    ╵               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/eventListeners.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js:2:27:
  2 │ import eventListeners from "./modifiers/eventListeners.js";
    ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/eventListeners.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:2:27:
  2 │ import eventListeners from "./modifiers/eventListeners.js";      
    ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./dom-utils/listScrollParents.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:3:30:
  3 │ import listScrollParents from "./dom-utils/listScrollParents.js";
    ╵                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js:3:26:
  3 │ import popperOffsets from "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js";
    ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:3:26:
  3 │ import popperOffsets from "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js";
    ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./dom-utils/getOffsetParent.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:4:28:
  4 │ import getOffsetParent from "./dom-utils/getOffsetParent.js";
    ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/computeStyles.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:4:26:
  4 │ import computeStyles from "./modifiers/computeStyles.js";
    ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/computeStyles.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js:4:26:
  4 │ import computeStyles from "./modifiers/computeStyles.js";
    ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/applyStyles.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js:5:24:
  5 │ import applyStyles from "./modifiers/applyStyles.js";
    ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/orderModifiers.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:6:27:
  6 │ import orderModifiers from "./utils/orderModifiers.js";
    ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/applyStyles.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:5:24:
  5 │ import applyStyles from "./modifiers/applyStyles.js";
    ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/debounce.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:7:21:
  7 │ import debounce from "./utils/debounce.js";
    ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/offset.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:6:19:
  6 │ import offset from "./modifiers/offset.js";
    ╵                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/validateModifiers.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:8:30:
  8 │ import validateModifiers from "./utils/validateModifiers.js";
    ╵                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/flip.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:7:17:
  7 │ import flip from "./modifiers/flip.js";
    ╵                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/preventOverflow.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:8:28:
  8 │ import preventOverflow from "./modifiers/preventOverflow.js";
    ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/uniqueBy.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:9:21:
  9 │ import uniqueBy from "./utils/uniqueBy.js";
    ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/arrow.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:9:18:
  9 │ import arrow from "./modifiers/arrow.js";
    ╵                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/getBasePlacement.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:10:29:
  10 │ import getBasePlacement from "./utils/getBasePlacement.js";
     ╵                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/mergeByName.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:11:24:
  11 │ import mergeByName from "./utils/mergeByName.js";
     ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/hide.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:10:17:
  10 │ import hide from "./modifiers/hide.js";
     ╵                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./modifiers/index.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:20:14:
  20 │ export * from "./modifiers/index.js";
     ╵               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./utils/detectOverflow.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:12:27:
  12 │ import detectOverflow from "./utils/detectOverflow.js";
     ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./dom-utils/instanceOf.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:13:26:
  13 │ import { isElement } from "./dom-utils/instanceOf.js";
     ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./getWindow.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getComputedStyle.js:1:22:
  1 │ import getWindow from "./getWindow.js";
    ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./instanceOf.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js:1:41:      
  1 │ import { isElement, isHTMLElement } from "./instanceOf.js";
    ╵                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "../utils/math.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js:2:22:      
  2 │ import { round } from "../utils/math.js";
    ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./getNodeScroll.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js:2:26:
  2 │ import getNodeScroll from "./getNodeScroll.js";
    ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./getNodeName.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js:3:24:
  3 │ import getNodeName from "./getNodeName.js";
    ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./getWindow.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js:3:22:      
  3 │ import getWindow from "./getWindow.js";
    ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./isLayoutViewport.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js:4:29:      
  4 │ import isLayoutViewport from "./isLayoutViewport.js";
    ╵                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./instanceOf.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js:4:30:
  4 │ import { isHTMLElement } from "./instanceOf.js";
    ╵                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./getWindowScrollBarX.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js:5:32:
  5 │ import getWindowScrollBarX from "./getWindowScrollBarX.js";
    ╵                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./isScrollParent.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js:7:27:
  7 │ import isScrollParent from "./isScrollParent.js";
    ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "../utils/math.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js:8:22:
  8 │ import { round } from "../utils/math.js";
    ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./instanceOf.js"

```
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getDocumentElement.js:1:26:
  1 │ import { isElement } from "./instanceOf.js";
    ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
  let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 37 errors:
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:3:30: ERROR: Could not resolve "./dom-utils/listScrollParents.js"
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:4:28: ERROR: Could not resolve "./dom-utils/getOffsetParent.js"
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:6:27: ERROR: Could not resolve "./utils/orderModifiers.js"
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:7:21: ERROR: Could not resolve "./utils/debounce.js"
node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js:8:30: ERROR: Could not resolve "./utils/validateModifiers.js"
...
    at failureErrorWithLog (D:\BOOKING APP\APP\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1636:15)
    at D:\BOOKING APP\APP\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1048:25       
    at D:\BOOKING APP\APP\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1512:9        
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) 
{
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 30,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 34,
        line: 3,
        lineText: 'import listScrollParents from "./dom-utils/listScrollParents.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./dom-utils/listScrollParents.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 28,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 32,
        line: 4,
        lineText: 'import getOffsetParent from "./dom-utils/getOffsetParent.js";',        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./dom-utils/getOffsetParent.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 27,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 27,
        line: 6,
        lineText: 'import orderModifiers from "./utils/orderModifiers.js";',      
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/orderModifiers.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 21,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 21,
        line: 7,
        lineText: 'import debounce from "./utils/debounce.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/debounce.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 30,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 30,
        line: 8,
        lineText: 'import validateModifiers from "./utils/validateModifiers.js";',        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/validateModifiers.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 21,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 21,
        line: 9,
        lineText: 'import uniqueBy from "./utils/uniqueBy.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/uniqueBy.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 29,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 29,
        line: 10,
        lineText: 'import getBasePlacement from "./utils/getBasePlacement.js";',  
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/getBasePlacement.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 24,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 24,
        line: 11,
        lineText: 'import mergeByName from "./utils/mergeByName.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/mergeByName.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 27,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 27,
        line: 12,
        lineText: 'import detectOverflow from "./utils/detectOverflow.js";',      
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./utils/detectOverflow.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.js',
        length: 27,
        line: 13,
        lineText: 'import { isElement } from "./dom-utils/instanceOf.js";',       
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./dom-utils/instanceOf.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 41,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js',
        length: 17,
        line: 1,
        lineText: 'import { isElement, isHTMLElement } from "./instanceOf.js";',  
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./instanceOf.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 22,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js',
        length: 18,
        line: 2,
        lineText: 'import { round } from "../utils/math.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "../utils/math.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 22,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js',
        length: 16,
        line: 3,
        lineText: 'import getWindow from "./getWindow.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./getWindow.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 29,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getBoundingClientRect.js',
        length: 23,
        line: 4,
        lineText: 'import isLayoutViewport from "./isLayoutViewport.js";',        
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./isLayoutViewport.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js',    
        length: 20,
        line: 2,
        lineText: 'import getNodeScroll from "./getNodeScroll.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./getNodeScroll.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 24,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js',    
        length: 18,
        line: 3,
        lineText: 'import getNodeName from "./getNodeName.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./getNodeName.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 30,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js',    
        length: 17,
        line: 4,
        lineText: 'import { isHTMLElement } from "./instanceOf.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./instanceOf.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 32,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js',    
        length: 26,
        line: 5,
        lineText: 'import getWindowScrollBarX from "./getWindowScrollBarX.js";',  
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./getWindowScrollBarX.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 27,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js',    
        length: 21,
        line: 7,
        lineText: 'import isScrollParent from "./isScrollParent.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./isScrollParent.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 22,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js',    
        length: 18,
        line: 8,
        lineText: 'import { round } from "../utils/math.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "../utils/math.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 22,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getComputedStyle.js',    
        length: 16,
        line: 1,
        lineText: 'import getWindow from "./getWindow.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./getWindow.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getDocumentElement.js',  
        length: 17,
        line: 1,
        lineText: 'import { isElement } from "./instanceOf.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./instanceOf.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 14,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js',
        length: 22,
        line: 2,
        lineText: 'export * from "./modifiers/index.js"; // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unused-modules',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/index.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 27,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js',
        length: 31,
        line: 2,
        lineText: 'import eventListeners from "./modifiers/eventListeners.js";',  
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/eventListeners.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js',
        length: 30,
        line: 3,
        lineText: 'import popperOffsets from "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js";',    
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js',
        length: 30,
        line: 4,
        lineText: 'import computeStyles from "./modifiers/computeStyles.js";',    
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/computeStyles.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 24,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js',
        length: 28,
        line: 5,
        lineText: 'import applyStyles from "./modifiers/applyStyles.js";',        
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/applyStyles.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 27,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 31,
        line: 2,
        lineText: 'import eventListeners from "./modifiers/eventListeners.js";',  
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/eventListeners.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 30,
        line: 3,
        lineText: 'import popperOffsets from "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js";',    
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/popperOffsets.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 26,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 30,
        line: 4,
        lineText: 'import computeStyles from "./modifiers/computeStyles.js";',    
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/computeStyles.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 24,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 28,
        line: 5,
        lineText: 'import applyStyles from "./modifiers/applyStyles.js";',        
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/applyStyles.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 19,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 23,
        line: 6,
        lineText: 'import offset from "./modifiers/offset.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/offset.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 17,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 21,
        line: 7,
        lineText: 'import flip from "./modifiers/flip.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/flip.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 28,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 32,
        line: 8,
        lineText: 'import preventOverflow from "./modifiers/preventOverflow.js";',        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/preventOverflow.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 18,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 22,
        line: 9,
        lineText: 'import arrow from "./modifiers/arrow.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/arrow.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 17,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 21,
        line: 10,
        lineText: 'import hide from "./modifiers/hide.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/hide.js"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 14,
        file: 'node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js',
        length: 22,
        line: 20,
        lineText: 'export * from "./modifiers/index.js";',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./modifiers/index.js"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Comment: did you run "npm install"?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue recently.

For some reason the `node_modules` `popperjs/core` did not seem to have the full set of files expected. An `npm i` checked `node_modules`, found it was installed, as the `package.lock` specified though.

The fix was to remove `@popperjs` folder manually, and then perform an `npm install`

Don't know how it got in that situation in the first place though!